# How to create this ViewEntity with TypeORM?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

Say I'm building an address book that has 4 tables: `user`, `contact`, `friend`, and `stranger`.

`contact` is the linking table connecting `user` with BOTH the `friend` and `stranger` tables. It's structured like:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ user_id ║ friend_id ║ stranger_id ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 5         ║ NULL        ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1       ║ NULL      ║ 65          ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 1       ║ 87        ║ NULL        ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I'd like to create a view that looks like:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ user_id ║ friend_id ║ stranger_id ║ contact_name ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 5         ║ NULL        ║ Barry        ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1       ║ NULL      ║ 65          ║ Gary         ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 1       ║ 87        ║ NULL        ║ Larry        ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

That is, I'd like a view I can query using `user_id` and get a list of all that user's contacts *with* the `name` column that's common to both `friend` and `stranger` tables.

Ideally, I'd like to implement this using TypeORM but just knowing the correct SQL for it would help as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try to define a [ViewEntity](https://typeorm.io/#/view-entities) which performs a left join between `contacts`, `friends` and `stranger` table. The resulting rows will then be mapped on to a `ContactWithName` object, whereby a new field `contact_name` is added which [concats](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-concat-function/) the `name` column of the `friends` and `stranger` table (`NULL` fields will be ignored).

```ts
@ViewEntity({
    expression: (connection: Connection) => connection.createQueryBuilder(Contact, "contact")
        .select   ('contact.id', 'id')
        .addSelect('contact.user_id', 'user_id')
        .addSelect('contact.friend_id', 'friend_id')
        .addSelect('contact.stranger_id', 'stranger_id')
        .addSelect('CONCAT(friend.name, stranger.name)', 'contact_name')
        .leftJoin (Friend, "friend")     // friend table
        .leftJoin (Stranger, "stranger") // stranger table
})
export class ContactWithName {

    @ViewColumn()
    id: number;

    @ViewColumn()
    user_id: number;

    @ViewColumn()
    friend_id: number;

    @ViewColumn()
    stranger_id: number;

    @ViewColumn()
    contact_name: string;

}
```

Then, you can query as usual for result sets: `getRepository(ContactWithName).find(...)`

Comment: Great answer ! The connection is now deprecated in the latest versions of typeorm  and this can be replaced with DataSource

Answer (score 1):

My version of SQL for your view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT co.id, co.user_id, co.friend_id,
       co.stranger_id, concat(f.name, s.name) AS contact_name
FROM contact co
LEFT JOIN friend f ON (co.friend_id = f.friend_id)
LEFT JOIN stranger s ON (co.stranger_id = s.stranger_id);
```

The function "concat" makes the magic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about you question. You should provide more information regarding how your data is stored in the dimension tables. I assume that `Friends` and `Stranger` tables contain a unique `id` and a column name. I understand that you would like to enrich your fact table (`Contact`) with data from both `Friends` and `Stranger`with the names coming in one single column. If this assumption is correct, then maybe this query might do it:

```
select c.id, c.user_id, c.friend_id, c.stranger_id, f.friend_name as contact_name
from #contact c
inner join #friend f
on c.friend_id = f.id
union
select c.id, c.user_id, c.friend_id, c.stranger_id, s.stranger_name as contact_name
from #contact c
inner join #stranger s
on c.stranger_id = s.id;
```

Feel free to provide more information if this doesn't solve your problem.