# NestJS How I make query to views in an database

Tags: database, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have one small problem, my question is how I make query to views in an database?. I'm based in this example [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448115/how-to-create-this-viewentity-with-typeorm/59664474#59664474)

- The name of database is **bue**(mysql)
- My **Views** is v1
- I use TYPEORM

My Code is one entity:

```
import { ViewEntity, Connection } from 'typeorm';

@ViewEntity({
    expression: (connection: Connection) => connection.createQueryBuilder()
    .select('id')
    .from(V1, 'v1'), }) 

}
export class V1 {

}
```

My error logs in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use View Entities, as a said in updated docs:
https://typeorm.io/#/view-entities

Ex:

```
@ViewEntity({ 
    expression: (connection: Connection) => connection.createQueryBuilder()
        .select("post.id", "id")
        .addSelect("post.name", "name")
        .addSelect("category.name", "categoryName")
        .from(Post, "post")
        .leftJoin(Category, "category", "category.id = post.categoryId")
})
```